# How to get all the instances of one object in a many-to-many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that relate to one another in a many to many relationship. I've established the queries with methods $this->belongsToMany() on both sides.

One table is called **Device**, the other one is called **Pos**. I wanna access all the instances of Device related to that Pos in the intermediate table using Eloquent.

This is Device model:

```
public function pos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pos', 'devices_pos')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

This is Pos model:

```
public function devices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Device', 'devices_pos')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I don't wanna make a DB query straight to 'devices_pos' table. I'd like to do it the Eloquent way.

Comment: Do you want to access the intermediate table? Look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could access all Devices from a Pos using the relation:

```
$pos = Pos::find($id);
$pos->devices; // this will return all the devices from that pos
```

And you could loop that to access each attribute from each device:

```
foreach($pos->devices as $device)
{
echo $device->anyDeviceAttribute;
}
```

For more info: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

Use the pivot attribute to access the intermediate table after accessing the relationship

```
$pos = Pos::find($id);

foreach ($pos->devices as $device) {
    echo $device->pivot->created_at; //returns created_at on the intermedite table 'devices_pos'
}
```